# First created PDF (generated w/ DomPDF) shows images - the rest don't

Tags: php, image, cakephp, dompdf, cakephp-2.4

I'm generating PDFs in a loop - one for each ticket in an order.

The first PDF displays all the images, but the next one and ALL after it show an error for the logo, and sponsor logos...etc:

> "Image not readable or empty"

**What would cause it to work fine for the first one (EVERY TIME), but then for any additional PDFs, it doesn't?**

The only thing I could think is that the images that don't show up on the 2nd+ PDFs are the ones that are on each.  The 2 images that DO show up on all of them are ones that are unique to each (the barcode and qr code).

It's the same script - it's even in a foreach loop.  And the logo that should be displaying on all of them is the same image.

I'm using CakePHP 2.4.5, but not sure that matters.

---

**The simplified foreach loop that creates the PDFs:**

```
foreach ($order['Ticket'] as $ticket) {
    //...

    $contentUrl = Router::url(array(
        'controller'=>'tickets',
        'action'=>'pdf_ticket',
        $ticket['id']),
        true
    );
    $pdf = $this->Pdf->generateSaveAndDisplay(
        $contentUrl,
        $ticket['id'],
        array('folder'=>'tickets', 'display' => false)
    );

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but perhaps it could be to do with the other images returning a 304 not modified header?  Have you tried cache-busting the image url?  (eg. myimage.jpg?nocache=123456)

Comment: I also got somehow this kind of issue, and that was resolved by creating a new instance of the PDF class in foreach loop with 2 seconds sleep in each iteration.

Comment: We don't know what's happening when you call `$this->Pdf->generateSaveAndDisplay()` so we can't review your usage of dompdf.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of dompdf? This sounds like an image cache problem. With 0.5.x and some versions of the 0.6.0 beta the image cache (static) object doesn't clean up correctly, resulting in a corrupted cache. So using dompdf more than once is buggy in these versions for images used in more than one render.

References:

- v0.6.0 PR: [Image cache reused after being cleared.](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/437)
- v0.6.0 PR: [datauri images are not cleared from cache](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/561)
- v0.5.x: [Image cache doesn't remove cached item from array](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/24)